# How to find the best combination that fits a distribution

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix

I'm trying to sample a dataframe in a way the sum of the contents fits a specific distribution.

Let's say I want to fill a basket with fruits, but at a time I can only do so by adding a mix of fruits, and my basket can only hold a certain amount of each fruit.
I can represent the contents of the dataframe in a matrix, like:

| Mix | apples | bananas | oranges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 |

My basket can hold 3 apples 3 bananas and 3 oranges, therefore if I choose mix1 AND mix2 that satisfies the maximum basket content.

Now my problem is that this dataframe contains tens of thousands of mixes, so searching for combinations in a greedy way would take a really long time. Is there a way to approximate the possible combinations? (I can even calculate with a little bit of error, i.e. although mix3 has one more banana, I can accept that combination if that helps lower the run time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem of runtime with python. The script runs in less than a second to filter the possible fruit baskets out of 10 millions lines

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a numpy array with 10.000.000 lines of random integers between 1 and 5 with shape (100000, 3)
arr = np.random.randint(low=1, high=6, size=(1000000, 3))
# Create a new dataframe with the random values and set the Mix column as the index
df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, columns=['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges'])
df.index.name = 'Mix'
display(df.head(3))

# Select all lines with at most 3 apples, bananas and oranges in a descending order:
display(df[(df.apples<=3) & (df.bananas<=3) & (df.oranges<=3)].sort_values(by=['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges'], ascending=False))
```

This is the generated output:

```
    apples  bananas oranges
Mix         
5   3   3   3
39  3   3   3
303 3   3   3
979 3   3   3
1019    3   3   3
... ... ... ...
998527  1   1   1
998799  1   1   1
999238  1   1   1
999280  1   1   1
999441  1   1   1
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I wanted to sway the ideation process to theoretics with this simple example so bad, i overlooked a critical point. The amount of fruits can be 50k+. Maybe at this point my question is rather fit to stackexchange, but nevertheless, my apologies.

Comment: Anyways, your answer indeed is valid to the original question, so let me accept it and close it here, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: That is going to be a large fruit basket and explains your concerns about the run time. Maybe you should ask a new question and this time provide a example of your dataframe or explain in a bit more detail how the 50k+ columns are formatted (i.e. integers or strings).

Answer (score 0):

you can use dataframe filters and let pandas do it efficiently instead of iterating over each row. make a new column with sum of all fruits in the mix. then add filters to your dataframe to weed out the obvious mixes that dont work. one filter could be total number of fruits should be <= the total number of fruits that can fit in your bag. you could add filters for each fruit also, if its more than the capacity. sort by the sum to get best combinations first